# Hangout like list notification on Android Wear

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

`Hangout` use a particular `Notification` that display the list of messages when swiping right on `Android Wear`. It shows all the messages  in a `ListView`.

Do they use a particular `Notification Style` (like `InboxStyle` or `BigTextStyle`)? Could it be a `Wear App`? (I don't think so, they are not accessible throght swiping)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are adding [Pages](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/pages.html) to their notification, allowing you to add additional content for Android Wear devices.

Example code from the link:

```
// Create builder for the main notification
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_message)
    .setContentTitle("Page 1")
    .setContentText("Short message")
    .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent);

// Create a big text style for the second page
BigTextStyle secondPageStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
secondPageStyle.setBigContentTitle("Page 2")
           .bigText("A lot of text...");

// Create second page notification
Notification secondPageNotification =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setStyle(secondPageStyle)
    .build();

// Add second page with wearable extender and extend the main notification
Notification twoPageNotification =
    new WearableExtender()
            .addPage(secondPageNotification)
            .extend(notificationBuilder)
            .build();

// Issue the notification
notificationManager =
    NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, twoPageNotification);
```

Comment: So you say they're using a BigTextStyle where they dump the whole list of messages in a single string, formatted via html or spans. I need to check if there are dividers, but those could be faked with underscores.

Comment: For the second page, yes just one long BigTextStyle

Comment: Do you have any idea how they manage to have it scrolled to the bottom? Even though there is a bunch of text on the page

Comment: @Leo - you'd want [setStartScrollBottom(true)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.WearableExtender.html#setStartScrollBottom(boolean))

Comment: @ianhanniballake is setStartScrollBottom(true) working for you,
because it is not working for me